# Is there some way I can start a (repeating) ping while the network is unreachable?

Tags: shell-script, networking, ping

My ping command (on Debian 6 or 7) will repeatedly attempt to ping a server even while the network is down, **if** the network was up when it was started. Is there some way to start ping while the network is down and get this same behavior?

Here's an example. If I start a repeating ping while the network is up, and while the ping is running, the network goes down, the ping continues to repeat. If the network comes back up, it will continue pinging:

```
me@here:~$ ping -n 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=46 time=117 ms
...
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=6 ttl=46 time=116 ms
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
...
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=108 ttl=46 time=694 ms
...
```

However, if the network is down when I run ping:

```
me@here:~$ ping -n 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
me@here:~$
```

This is the same unreachable network problem, but ping doesn't keep trying until the network is up again, like it had before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a while loop in a shell script:

```sh
failed=1 # any number not equal to zero
while [ $failed -ne 0 ]
do
   ping -n 8.8.8.8
   failed=$?
done
# after the  $? becomes "0" it will get out of the while loop
echo "ping succeeded"
```

To stop keep printing the `connect: Network is unreachable` message you can edit the line with ping like this:

```sh
ping -n 8.8.8.8 2> /dev/null
```

Or you can add a `sleep` in the loop to reduce the number of those messages.

The script can be simplified to

```sh
while ! ping -n 8.8.8.8
do
    sleep 1
done
```

Which lets it be written in one line:

```sh
while ! ping -n 8.8.8.8; do sleep 1; done
```

Comment: An advantage to this solution is that you can use the `-a` option to hear beeps as soon as the network comes up. A disadvantage is that in the final statistics, the early failures are not counted.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, `ping` will not run if it cannot open a socket on an interface (because the interface is down).  If you check your devices with `ip link show`, you will see which devices are *up* or *down*.

Try activating the network device first.

```
$ sudo ip link set <iface> up
$ ping -n 8.8.8.8
```

I've tested this on my Arch Linux box with a *down* wifi interface, and an *up* virtual ethernet (no IP address assigned) interface.  A `ping` on the former quits, while the latter `ping` is continuous.

Otherwise, use networker's shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fping` with its `-l` and `-I` options, instead of `ping`. This requires knowing the name of the interface, and running as root:

```
root@here:~# fping -l -I wlan0 -n 8.8.8.8

me@here:~$ sudo fping -l -I eth0 -n 8.8.8.8
```